# Text editor for Raspbian Lite

Tags: ssh, pi-3b+, raspbian-buster

I am using the [Raspbian Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/) image for the first time and realize there isn't any text editor. I am also using SSH to bring up the remote Raspberry Pi terminal on a LAN from a Windows 10 laptop.

How can I edit files with a text editor on Raspbian Lite? Can I do this through an SSH connection to a remote Raspberry Pi on a LAN?

[*This* also helped me on Nano](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/11/quick-guide-to-nano-text-editor-on-the-raspberry-pi/)

Comment: On an easy/simple to complex/difficult scale, at the former end you have things like `nano`, on the latter `vim` and `emacs` which have IDE like features.   I'd guess any of the non-DOS centric things listed here are available: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_text_editors#Text_user_interface  If you'd rather use something you are familiar with on the Windows box you can probably remote mount the/a filesystem on the Pi.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano). It comes as standard on the majority of Linux distributions. To use it, simply type `nano` followed by the name/path to the file you want to edit.

For example, to create and edit a new file called `test`, type

```
nano test
```

To edit an existing file, such as [fstab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab), type

```
nano /etc/fstab
```

Or navigate into the `etc` directory (`cd /etc`) and type

```
nano fstab
```

Note some files will require root privileges to edit so you'll need to use `sudo` to edit. Be careful with those as that's where you may cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio Code, the [remote-ssh](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) extension is your best best friend. 
Disclaimer - This starts a vscode server on the RPi and takes up significant memory. I have had issues when using this setup to build a website using Vite+React+TS and running a flask server simultaneously.